# Can't access image from html page in maven

Tags: java, html, maven

I am new to maven web application, below is my eclipse directory..

```
MyProject
-- src
------main
----------resources
-------------------images
--------------------------myimage.png
----------webapp
----------------index.html
----------WEB-INF
----------------web.xml
```

Here is my index.html source.

```
<img alt="" src="images/myimage.png">
```

When I run this image is not shown in browser. I heard somewhere we should declare/map the resource directory in web.xml file but I did not found anything.

I have tried every possible ways in `img src` path.

**I just need to show the image in my html page.**

Can anybody help..

Comment: just put `images` folder to `webapp` folder

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

basic-maven-project:

```
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- src
 |   |-- main
 |   |   |-- java
 |   |   |-- resources -- Images folder under here.
 |   |   `-- webapp

 |   |       `-- WEB-INF
 |   `-- test

 |       |-- java

 |       `-- resources
    `-- target
 |-- classes
   `-- test-classes
```

Try:

```
<img alt="" src="resources/images/myimage.png">
```

For a more thorough description see the answer to this SO question :[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464816/maven-packaging-images-in-the-root-of-the-jar-file) and [How to pack resources in a Maven Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134179/how-to-pack-resources-in-a-maven-project).

Answer (score 1):

As described on the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) of the maven-war-plugin, you should put those files under `src/main/webapp`. Only if you need images on the classpath (which is not the case), you should put them under `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code in jsp as:

```
<img id="ctl01_imgCOESign" src="<%=URI.create(request.getRequestURL().toString()).resolve(request.getContextPath())%>/images/coesign.jpg">
```