# Dropwizard cannot load client side files

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

i have following directory structure of dropwizard java application.I have my client side files linked in index.html.

```
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- java
|   |   |-- resources 
|   |   |   |--assets
|   |   |   |  |--css
|   |   |   |  |--js   all js files
|   |   |   |  |--lib all libraries
|   |   |   |  |--index.html
```

Index.html contains links like

```
<link href="/css/bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>  
<script src="/lib/satellizer.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried almost every kind of link here.when running in xampp this client side is running as well as all the libraries are loaded but here index.html is loaded while the files referenced in it are not loading.please any help here.

NOTE:

i have seen many SO posts [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465827/cant-access-image-from-html-page-in-maven?lq=1)  AND How to pack resources in a Maven Project?"">HERE etc but all in vain.

**EDIT**:

**helloworldapplication.java:**

```
 package com.example.helloworld;

 import io.dropwizard.Application;
 import io.dropwizard.assets.AssetsBundle;
 import io.dropwizard.client.JerseyClientBuilder;
 import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;
 import io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle;
 import io.dropwizard.migrations.MigrationsBundle;
 import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
 import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

 import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;

 import       com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldConfiguration.ClientSecretsConfiguration;
 import com.example.helloworld.auth.AuthFilter;
 import com.example.helloworld.core.User;
 import com.example.helloworld.db.UserDAO;
 import com.example.helloworld.resources.AuthResource;
 import com.example.helloworld.resources.ClientResource;
 import com.example.helloworld.resources.UserResource;

 public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application<HelloWorldConfiguration> {
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
   new HelloWorldApplication().run(args);
 }

 private final HibernateBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration> hibernateBundle =
  new HibernateBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration>(User.class) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(final   HelloWorldConfiguration configuration) {
      return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
  };

    @Override
   public String getName() {
    return "hello-world";
    }

   @Override
   public void initialize(final Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
   bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<HelloWorldConfiguration>() {
  @Override
  public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(final HelloWorldConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
  }
});

bootstrap.addBundle(hibernateBundle);

bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/js/bundle.js", "/bundle.js", null, "bundle"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/css", "/stylesheets", null, "css"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/lib/lib.js", "/lib.js", null, "lib"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/vendor", "/vendor", null, "vendor"));
  }

    @Override
  public void run(final HelloWorldConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment)
  throws ClassNotFoundException {

    final UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
    final Client client =
    new  JerseyClientBuilder(environment).using(configuration.getJerseyClient())
        .build(getName());
    final ClientSecretsConfiguration clientSecrets = configuration.getClientSecrets();

    environment.jersey().register(new ClientResource());
    environment.jersey().register(new UserResource(dao));
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthResource(client, dao, clientSecrets));

   environment.servlets().addFilter("AuthFilter", new AuthFilter())
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/api/me");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post some more information? Your main application class and server config might be useful - you'll need to ensure you've added the AssetsBundle as detailed at http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/core.html#serving-assets

Comment: i have edited y question with file following this link.

Answer (score 0):

Link ur client side resources to index.html (Please provide the proper path under resources folder **src/main/resources**)

Change your AssetsBundle constructor for adding the resource bundle files to dropwizard

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<FulfilmentOptionsConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/*", "/index"));
}
```

Comment: Now error is "src/main/resources/assets/bundle.js" is not an absolute path.